# Visual Studio Code is not compiling live

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass

Anyone have an idea why live sass compiler extension on vs code is not working?

While editing the file, changes do not appear on screen.

Commenting code that is in the current route will not crush the system and will not produce an error.
The CLI will declare `webpack compiled successfully Compiled successfully!`

I did try to reinstall extension and to edit path saving settings and even to reinstall vs code but nothing.
The problem is that it worked for a short period of time and just stopped, like it is some bug or something because it is constantly showing 'working on it..' but nothing is happening. Is there some issue with extension or it could be up to myself?

Please if someone have an idea what could cause this problem, I will appreciate answer.

thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You more than likely have invalid syntax somewhere in your scss.
I once had the same issue that was caused by an empty property.

Empty properties such as `background-image: linear-gradient(), url();` will hault the compiler which will therefore not continue watching your scss, thus the eternal "working on it..".

Comment: Before making this answer you should leave some comments trying to figure out the issue. As it is the answer is not completely bad but it's it's not precise enough to be helpful for other people

Comment: In my case the problem turned out to be in settings for compatible browsers list. `defaults and not ie 11` apparently does not work. #forwhomitmayconcern

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue so I went through my SASS code and realized I had added a media query that was empty. I recommend you go through the whole source making sure you have all ';' and values added. If you think it could be a line, try deleting or commenting out and running it again!

Answer (score -1):

You probably have installed some other extension that is disabling SASS from running as it should. Trying uninstalling other text/styling extensions.